# How do I display particles above the UI in Game scene?

Tags: user-interface

I made a trail particle that follows the image of a canvas child, and I hope it shows above the UI in the game scene.

I changed the canvas from overlay canvas to camera canvas to solve this problem. Adjusted the canvas and normal distance. I adjusted the curling mask on the camera, but I can't see it, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost done.Change the renderer mode on the canvas from the screen space overlay to the screen space camera.
And check the order of layers on the canvas and the order of layers on the particles. Set the order of the particle layers above the order of the canvas layers

Answer (score 0):

First, create an overlay UI layer.
Create another camera Change the render type of the over UI camera to overlay layer Also set the curling mask to over UI. Exclude only Over UI from the kerneling mask of the main camera. Finally, change the render mode to the camera in the screen space.